Is there a way to fix the JavaFX error "ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID" in my Java web browser?

My code Java for this problem:

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;

public class progma extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] x) {
        launch(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage prime) {
        WebView w = new WebView();
        WebEngine webengine = w.getEngine();
        TextField urlField = new TextField(); // Thêm TextField cho URL

        // Xử lý sự kiện khi nhấn Enter trong TextField
        urlField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    String url = urlField.getText();
                    webengine.load(url);
                }
            }
        });

        webengine.load("https://google.com");

        VBox root = new VBox();

        // Thêm TextField vào VBox
        root.getChildren().add(urlField);

        // Thêm WebView vào VBox
        root.getChildren().add(w);

        Scene s = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        prime.setTitle("IE for 2024");
        prime.setScene(s);
        prime.show();

        // Lắng nghe sự thay đổi của cả chiều rộng và chiều cao của Scene
        s.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                w.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        });

        s.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number old, Number new1) {
                w.setPrefHeight(new1.doubleValue());
            }
        });
    }
}

When I run the program and go to an URL (like https://youtube.com), it show the error like:
thg 5 11, 2024 8:46:33 CH com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCMediaPlayerImpl onError
WARNING: onError, errCode=260, msg=ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
thg 5 11, 2024 8:46:33 CH com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCMediaPlayerImpl onError
WARNING: onError, errCode=260, msg=ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
thg 5 11, 2024 8:46:33 CH com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCMediaPlayerImpl onError
WARNING: onError, errCode=260, msg=ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
thg 5 11, 2024 8:46:33 CH com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCMediaPlayerImpl onError
WARNING: onError, errCode=260, msg=ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID

I want to find a way to fix this error.
I try to fix the problem at my code, but it not have any useful, i think is in the JavaFX or the code, or the URL.
My question for this problem (you can answer any question you know):

It have a way to fix this error?
Where this error begin?
How to fix the error?


Additional information:


OS: Windows 10
Java version: Java 21.0.3
JavaFX: OpenJFX 21.0.3


As far as I know, the underlying implementation of WebEngine cannot be modified or augmented.  Side note: Your property listeners are doing the work that a layout should be doing.  If you use a BorderPane instead of a VBox, you won’t need those listeners at all.

I'm using your comment, but it show this error like:
`[thread 1432 also had an error]

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
[thread 12908 also had an error]#
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff900000010, pid=10204, tid=5820

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (21.0.3+7) (build 21.0.3+7-LTS-152)
`

I’m not able to reproduce that crash.  But I don’t have access to a Windows 10 system.  Are you able to try it on Windows 11?

See: Possible causes of Java VM EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION?  Perhaps you have incorrect native libraries or mixed JavaFX module versions.  Hard to know without knowing how you are building and running the software.
